# Server Side Script running continuous without servlet

Tags: java, ajax, html, hibernate, servlets

Hello I am working on a web project using html5 and Java with hibernate framework and ajax as a bridge between them. 
I have developed servlets thats are mapped with html5 forms and send data through ajax. 
The problem i am facing is that i cant figure out how to run a script on the server which is not part of a servlet.

The script is an independent module that would get data from the database and manipulate it continiously in a loop when the server is started. The only knowledge of server side manipulations are of a servlets which needs to be called using a button. However the script i want to run in a loop does not require a button it should be running as soon as the server starts and irrespective of the servlets should continue running

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There is no work done in this regard yet i am just stuck in what approach to obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you assume that a servlet is something that is bound to an HTTP request (like the execution of scripts in PHP).

Well... It is not.

A servlet based application is indeed a full blown application. You start it, and it runs. On and on. The servlet API just defines some ways to interact with you application and that API targets HTTP as a communication protocol primarily, but can even be used for other protocols.

Anyway: Too archieve your goal you probably want to implement a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). This will fire as soon as your sevlet application is started and once it is stopped. Usually you don't start and stop your application randomly, but only if you update your application or the like. In these cases there is hardly away around aborting your loop.

In this ServletContextListener of yours you can start your own threads of your own liking and keep them running as you please. You should also add a mechanism for shutdown if your server is stopped, because otherwise a server restart results in your threads forcefully beeing terminated in an undefined state and/or memory leaks. As I mentioned the shutdown will only happen in situation when there is hardly a way around a shutdown. Your application can run for years without a shutdown.

You need to register your ServletContextListener in your web.xml file so that it has some effect.

Comment: thanks could you give a small example of how to implement them ?

Comment: @Fahdie: The explainations should have given you a good start. Search for `ServletContextCotextListener example` or the like on google and you'll find some examples. If you get stuck, feel free to ask yet another question here with your new problem.